# Html helper for DateTime Date only with using localization

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, razor

I searched for an answer to my question, which is about how to make a *date only* input equipped with custom date picker in Razor ASP MVC.
The core of the problem is that I also implemented **localisation** to my app.

**Firstly** I added attribute to to my parameter in model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

This is causing troubles when the language of the application is switched, because the format is valid for only one language.

**Second approach** was to add another attribute to model class:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

With this, I achieved that Chrome/Opera/Vivaldi offered a browser integrated date picker.

```
<input type="date"/>
```

However, this did not work correctly, because it used browser language and not user selected language for the application. So server expects dates in different format as it might be posted to. So the validation fails. On the other hand, the good old IE showed simple input field which had date of correct format inside.

**Third approach** was converting DateTime object to local string in HTML helper with ToShortDateString() function:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConstructionStart_PLANNED.ToShortDateString(), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

The results as an exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<input type="date"/>` in Chrome and Edge renders the browsers HTML-5 datepicker which posts back in ISO format so will always be correctly bound to a `DateTime` (validation will not fail).

Comment: Yes, but in case user has Chrome language set to English, but wants to use my app in German language, the display will be MM/DD/YYYY instead of DD.MM.YYYY.

Comment: The whole point of the HTML5 datepicker is to display the dates in the format of the users device :). But the rest of what you saying is unclear - you have hard-coded a date format so its only ever displayed in that format (not based on any localization)

Comment: So if I want to display the dates according to users language selection, the best solution is to have plain text input?
I abandoned the hard-coded approach because of that.

Comment: Or a jQuery datepicker formatted to display the date in the selected format

Comment: This may actually be the solution. I will try.